# Why is application:didReceiveLocalNotification's notification parameter NULL on entry?

Tags: ios, notifications

In the debugger, application:didReceiveLocalNotification: has a NULL entry.  The app is being launched through a local notification in the notification bar.  The documentation describes the notification (second) parameter the following way:

A local notification that encapsulates details about the notification, potentially including custom data.

This is being tested on an iOS6 device, not the simulator which has known to have bugs with local notifications.

In what situation is this NULL, and how can I get the notification that launched the app?

Comment: This doesn't happen on the simulator.  On there, I am getting non-NULL notifications.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature branch was shelved for a more pressing matter so I did not.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out yesterday after reading apple's documentation a little more thoroughly.

Basically, there is another method that iOS uses in certain cases to communicate a UILocalNotification to your application: `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. This method contains the UILocalNotification, found in its options dictionary via the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`. It is this method that will contain your notification when, for example, your application wasn't running but was started by iOS because the user clicked the notification in Notification Center. Obviously, there isn't always a UILocalNotification present in its options dictionary.

Read here for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope that helps you out!